# Got some Issues Building a Project Using mysql-connector-cpp with CMake

Tags: mysql, cmake

I'm trying to build a project which use `mysql-connector-cpp` locally, with CMake.

Here is my file tree:

```
src/
├─ app/
├─ common/
├─ core/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
ThirdParty/
├─ mysql-connector-cpp/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

`root/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
  message("Debug build.")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
  message("Release build.")
endif()

set(application_name "my_project")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)

set(application_version "1.0.2")
set(PROJECT_VER ${application_version})
set(WITH_JDBC ON)

project (${application_name} LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_subdirectory(ThirdParty)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`ThirdParty/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
add_subdirectory(mysql-connector-cpp)
```

And here is the error message when I try to build:

```bash
Release build.
CMake Deprecation Warning at ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:32 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error: File /home/username/workspace/my_project/driver/version_info.h.cmake does not exist.
CMake Error at ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:56 (CONFIGURE_FILE):
  CONFIGURE_FILE Problem configuring file


-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include
CMake Error at ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:311 (INCLUDE):
  INCLUDE could not find requested file:

    /home/username/workspace/my_project/FindMySQL.cmake


CMake Warning at ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:335 (MESSAGE):
  libmysqlclient and connector compilers mismatch:

  libmysqlclient:

  connector: GNU 4.8.5.


-- USE_SERVER_FLAGS : ON
-- Environment compile flags:   
-- Environment link flags: 
CMake Error: File /home/username/workspace/my_project/cppconn/version_info.h.cmake does not exist.
CMake Error at ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:356 (CONFIGURE_FILE):
  CONFIGURE_FILE Problem configuring file


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CPack.cmake:685 (message):
  CPack license resource file:
  "/home/username/workspace/my_project/LICENSE"
  could not be found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CPack.cmake:690 (cpack_check_file_exists)
  ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:477 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CPack.cmake:685 (message):
  CPack readme resource file:
  "/home/username/workspace/my_project/README"
  could not be found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CPack.cmake:691 (cpack_check_file_exists)
  ThirdParty/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:477 (INCLUDE)


-- Installation path is: /usr/local   (overwrite with -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/your/path)
-- Using static libmysql binding
-- DT_RPATH will not be set
-- Configuring driver
-- MySQL dynamic load test library: MYSQLCPPCONN_DYNLOAD_MYSQL_LIB-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring examples
-- Configuring test cases
-- Configuring tests framework lib
-- Configuring C/J junit tests port
-- MySQL dynamic load test library: MYSQLCPPCONN_DYNLOAD_MYSQL_LIB-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring unit tests
-- Configuring unit tests - examples
-- Configuring unit tests - connection
-- Configuring unit tests - databasemetadata
-- Configuring unit tests - resultsetmetadata
-- Configuring unit tests - resultset
-- Configuring unit tests - savepoint
-- Configuring unit tests - preparedstatement
-- Configuring unit tests - parametermetadata
-- Configuring unit tests - art_resultset
-- Configuring unit tests - statement
-- Configuring unit tests - uri
-- Configuring unit tests - variant
-- Configuring performance test - statement
-- Configuring bugs test cases - unsorted
-- Configuring unit tests - group template_bug
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

> **Update:** Proceeding with `mysql-connector-cpp version 8.1.0` solved my
> problem. It's compatible with `version 1.1`

So I updated include headers with `jdbc/` prefix, now I'm stuck on another level.

`src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(common)
add_subdirectory(core)
```

`src/core/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
set(source
    src/my_message.cpp
)

add_library(core ${source})

target_link_libraries(core PUBLIC common)
target_link_libraries(core PUBLIC mysql-connector-cpp)

target_include_directories(core PUBLIC inc)
target_include_directories(core PRIVATE inc/core)
```

`Build message:`

```bash
In file included from /home/username/workspace/my_project/src/core/src/my_message.cpp:13:
/home/username/workspace/my_project/src/core/inc/core/my_message.h:19:10: fatal error: jdbc/driver/mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory
 #include "jdbc/driver/mysql_connection.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/build.make:76: src/core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/my_message.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1418: src/core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Comment: If you are trying to build version 1.1 of mysql-connector-cpp, then it is not intended to be build as a CMake subproject. E.g. the erroneous line [CMakeLists.txt:56](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/blob/1.1/CMakeLists.txt#L56) dereferences `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` variable, which always refers to the top-level directory.

Comment: Yes I was tring to build `version 1.1`. So I decided to proceed with `version 8.1.0` because of it's `version 1.1` compatibility. This solved my main problem. Thanks for answer @Tsyvarev. 

So now I'm stuck at another step :)